# jQuery ajax call gives unexpected error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Error recieved (Chrome): **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

Script, call:

```
var frypeurl = 'http://www.draugiem.lv/say/ext/like_count.php';
$.ajax({
    url : frypeurl,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossDomain : true,
    data : { url : 'http://example.com/' },
    headers : { 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'X-Request' : 'JSON' },
    success : function(json){
        console.log(json);
        $('#frypecount').text(json.count);
    }
});
```

When it's accessed from browser, it returns normal result, [see here](http://www.draugiem.lv/say/ext/like_count.php?url=http://example.com/). (`{"count":"0"}`)

Have no idea what is causing it, tried it before with simply `$.getJSON();`, but returns same error, hence the `headers`, `crossDomain` parameters.

What could be the problem?

One thing I'd like to add, that's the biggest social network here in Latvia, and they have a weird API, functioning wise and coding too, probably. So I still have a guess that it's a problem on their side. I've messaged them, but no response yet.

Comment: Is your Website in the same domain of `frypeurl` (**draugiem.lv**)?

Comment: @alesdario, no, it's not. P.S. I've updated the url parameter, so you guys can try it out.

Comment: Have you tried removing the whitespace between url : frypeurl, for example? Could be that Chrome doesn't like it when you have those whitespaces. So it would be url: frypeurl,.

Comment: @Willempie, tried now, no difference.

Comment: @Tom you can't do cross site AJAX request (it's a security browser setting)

Comment: @alesdario thr `crossDomain:true` is there to take of it

Comment: @alesdario, that's why there's JSONP. And if not, then how come twitter/facebook works with almost the same script (except the urls)?

Comment: But that doesn't help, if draugiem.lv doesn't send the correct CORS headers back. For JSONP, it doesn't seem to support it in a standard way. Adding `&callback=foo` doesn't change the request.

Comment: As Boldewyn says: above code is okay but the answer from the server has errors. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/avall/hdAjC/ . error window contains errors from an answer.

Comment: Some of you please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Tom ... iframe. Btw, try `data : { 'url' : 'http://example.com/' },`

Comment: @alesdario, huh, no point if the returned answer contains errors. Client side is OK, seems that the server side code (draugiem.lv) has problems. And iframe is not an option this time.

Comment: @Tom If server side code has problems post your server side code.

Comment: @alesdario do you even keep track of this conversation? o_0

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure we are understanding. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing weird. You need to pass callback function by the query string

```
$.getJSON(frypeurl+"?callback=?", {
  url: "http://example.com/"
}, function(json){
  console.log(json);
  $("#frypecount").text(json.count);
});
```

Comment: ... I'll allow myself not to comment on this situation. Thanks!

Comment: I am still getting the same error by both the methods `$.ajax({..})` and `$.getJSON(..)`. However i am not passing any url as parameter as you have mentioned.